# How to add drop down as child node in jquery dynatree

Tags: javascript, user-interface, drop-down-menu, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

How can I add a dropdown as a child node for jquery dynatree? I have tried it, But it's not working. However adding a text field as node works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will add dropdown after the DOM is ready

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#dropdown").append("<option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option>");

    })
</script>
<body>
    <select id="dropdown"></select>
</body>
```